# python convert timestamp without year-month-day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with time column as string and I should convert it to a timestamp only with h:m:sec.ms . Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'time': ['02:21:18.110']})
df.time= pd.to_datetime(df.time , format="%H:%M:%S.%f")
df # I get 1900-01-01 02:21:18.110
```

Without format flag, I get current day 2020-12-16. How can I get the stamp without year-month-day which seemingly always is included. Thanks!

Comment: pandas does not handle date and time separately. you either have a default date (if no date supplied) or a default time (if no time supplied). stripping one of the two (e.g. with`.dt.time`) will leave you with a column of datatype object instead of datetime64.

Comment: great point! So no way then to get only time-part as datetime type? (see below the answer )

Comment: Datatype object means `datetime.time` object in this context (check `type(df.time.iloc[0])` for the given answer). That's Python's standard lib datetime, which means you can't make use of pandas' [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need processing values later by some datetimelike methods better is convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) instead times:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
print (df)
                    time
0 0 days 02:21:18.110000
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew you would come over with a helpful comment as always :)

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'time': ['02:21:18.110']})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.time

In [1023]: df
Out[1023]: 
              time
0  02:21:18.110000
```

Comment: I noticed now: this gives me an object. How can I get it as datetime which I can then use it e.g for resampling the data? Could you elaborate a bit on this converting?

Comment: @physiker - Then use `timedeltas` instead times, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65321699/2901002)